# In ProTools, how does one record live volume changes?

Tags: pro-tools

For instance, I am replaying a track I just recorded, but I want to mute some parts of it on the playback.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use automation.  There's a drop down menu on each of the channel strips that will usually read "off".  Pick one of the automation modes, probably "latch" (or "write").  There's an explanation of the modes [here](http://en.wikiaudio.org/Pro_Tools%3aautomation_modes).

Comment: Joe Mac the heart attack! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have automated faders
you can adjust the volume in another way.
It depends on if we're talking about midi volume or audio,
but the answer for both can be found in the same place.

Go to the actual track.
look to the left of where it shows your inputs and outputs
there's a button that usually says "notes" (if it doesn't just look for the big button under your track name)
just click on this,
a menu will drop down
midi volume and a few other ones like panning, modulation and whatever else will show up.
Midi volume or regular volume will allow you to adjust the volume wherever you want with the pencil tool.

Comment: I actually can't remember if the midi volume and regular volume are the same tool or not,
but I didn't want to mislead you by accident. also, if you want to adjust how hard the note is played in midi
use velocity under the same button I told you to click to find midi volume.